# offchain worker choose key to sign and send

Tags: offchain-worker, offchain, offchain-storage

I have multiple keys in my node storage with offchain worker running, there are currently 2 ways to sign and send transactions, it is done either for all of the keys stored locally, or 1 unspecified key(for_any). Could you please tell me how i can choose a particular key to sign and send transaction for offchain worker. there is with_filter function, but it is unclear how to use it because  accounts_from_keys and keystore_accounts of offchain crate are private methods. Ideally, depending on conditions, i would like to choose what exactly offchain worker key to use to sign and send the transaction. Thank you!

The setup: in my pallet where i use offchain worker, i insert multiple keys under the same key type.